# Trying to rar all subdirectories in a directory, not raring sub directories with folders in them

Tags: command-line, directory, compression, rar

I'm trying to rar all of the subdirectories inside of a directory into their own separate .rar files using the text below:

```
for dir in */
do
base=$(basename "$dir")
rar a "${base}" "$dir"
done
```

The only problem I'm running into is that when it attempts to rar one of the subdirectories that does not have files inside of it, but rather folders inside it gives me the error `WARNING: No Files`. An example of this would be `/main directory/subdirectory` to be `/rared/folder/actual files/`. Sub directories that have folders inside of them do not get rared, but give the no files error. Anything I can do to the command I'm running to fix this?

Comment: You can do this in one line with the find command if you like AND it will take care of hidden directories too! `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec your_rar_command_here \;` Of course you need to look up the syntax for the -exec switch and don't forget ` \;` at the end with a leading space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the -r flag will add subdirectories:

```
for dir in */; do rar a -r "${dir%/}.rar" "$dir"; done
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a destination for the .rar files to go to when they're completed in that code? I'd like for them to go onto a different drive.

Comment: Yes, just change the output path. for dir in */; do rar a -r "/home/LionParty/directory/${dir%/}.rar" "$dir"; done